# How can I justify text in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

I made a little text in HTML and it's looking fine, but I want it to be neatly stacked, or neatly aligned. Link one shows what I have right now, and link two shows what I want. Please ignore the red "Verdana".

This is what I have now, and what I don't want:
http://postimg.org/image/hho1sip5b/c9d22691/

This is what I don't have yet, but what I want:
http://postimg.org/image/7j5y11wjn/3d5e5ca5/

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="left">
  <p style="text-align: justify; height: 7px;">&nbsp;</p>

  <p style="line-height: 22px; font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana; ">
    <span style="letter-spacing: 1px">Big-ass piece of not-so-interesting text</span>
  </p>

  <p style="line-height: 28px; font-size: 18px; font-family: GillSans-Light; ">
    REDRUM
    <br>NIEUWE KAZERNELAAN 2-3
    <br>6711 JC EDE
    <br>POSTBUS 8193
    <br>6710 AD EDE
  </p>
</div>
```

All help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `text-align: justify` on an element with no text... try applying it to your actual text and it should work!

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! I'll verify your answer as correct as soon as Stackoverflow allows me to!